# Python gives unexpected end of regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to check strings against a patter. It works fine on the console:

```
if re.match('(?!.*example).*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s{0,}(.*)\s{0,}\/\s{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}','rains . cat / dog'):
    print 'ok'
```

But when I want to use it in my Django code:

```
pat = "(?!.*example).*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s{0,}(.*)\s{0,}\/\s{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}"

if re.match(pat, body):
    return True
```

I get this error:

```
unexpected end of regular expression
```

Following suggestions on other answers I also tried `//` and `////` instead of `/` but could not get it to work.

So wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue; your second example works fine for me.

Comment: Is Django running on the same version of Python as your console?

Comment: This happens on my django app.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn my python console runs `Python 2.7.12`. Not sure how to check django's python exact version. The folder inside virtualenv' lib is `python2.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **r** before regex pattern.
Try with this:

```
pat = r'(?!.*example).*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s{0,}(.*)\s{0,}\/\s{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}'
```

Or you can use `\`.

```
pat = "(?!.*example).*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\\s{0,}(.*)\\s{0,}\\/\\s{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}"
```

Comment: I thought this too, but since Python retains the '\' when the escape sequence is unrecognized, the string will (coincidentally) be interpreted correctly.